# How to update a property of a collection with value stored in an enum with respect to the value of property

Tags: c#, linq, enums

The title might be confusing. But here I am going to provide the complete picture of the problem.
I have a response which is a collection of class Member.

```
public class Member
{
  public int Identifier {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<string> Services {get;set}
}
```

In Services I get some fixed numeric values in form of string (like 1,3,5,6,9) as mentioned below

```
Member m1= new Member();
m1.Services= new List<string>() {"1","3"}
Member m2= new Member();
m2.Services= new List<string>() {"5","9"}
```

I have an enum which has some values corresponding to these fixed numeric values as mentioned below

```
public enum ServiceValues
{
  ABC=1,
  CDE=3,
  DEF=5,
  GHI=6,
  XYZ=9,
}
```

So In m1.Services I want to return {"ABD","CDE"} and in m2.Services I want to return {"DEF","XYZ"}

Though I know some dirty ways, but I want to achieve this in best possible way.

Comment: Well, this is hardly complete. First, what flavor of LINQ is this about? Second *In Services I get numeric values* - I only see string values and we have to guess the relation to the enum. *I know some dirty ways* - well, show at least one, that will explain more than words.

Comment: It would help to see a sample of a `Member` object, there seems to be some confusion as to what `Member.Services` contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an anonymous type is good enough for you, and assuming you want return an object that has both the `Identifier` and the list of `Services` you can do:

```
private Services ToService(string str)
{
    return (Services)Enum.Parse(typeof(Services), str);
}
...
var result = members.Select(member => new 
    {
        member.Identifier, 
        Services = members.Services.Select(ToService)
    });
```

Comment: I don't think your syntax for `Enum.TryParse` is valid - the first argument should be a string value, the second an `out` parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I see you modified to `Enum.Parse` - I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: yea, it was a typo, sorry

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to `Enum.TryParse` the values in your `string` collection, then use the resulting `Services` enum value to get a textual name. Something along the lines of:

```
var members = GetCollectionOfMember();

foreach(var member in members)
{
    foreach(var serviceString in member.Services)
    {
        Services service;
        if(Enum.TryParse<Services>(serviceString, out service))
        {
             var serviceName = service.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: really? please comment...or was that just retaliatory?

Comment: read closely now....`serviceString` comes from `member.Services`. OP said: `In Services I get numeric values...`. So parse `serviceString` (the numeric value as a string) into it's enum equivalent, then get the name of that enum value.

Comment: @Save see OP's recent update - `member.Services` is indeed a list of integers, as strings, that represent the enum values. Your retaliatory down-vote (or, lack of understanding) is interesting, because you made the exact same assumption in your answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84014/discussion-between-save-and-kaveman).